# What's the speed limit for things with mass?

Tags: special-relativity, mass, speed-of-light, speed

So the speed limit of the universe is 299 792 458 m/s, but only massless things like photons can archieve this speed. Since things that have mass can reach 99.99999...% speed of light, does that mean the speed limit for things with mass is 299 792 457 m/s? Because it's not the speed of light, it should be possible, right?

Comment: $299792457.5>299792457$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(mathematics)

Answer (score 2):

The limit is $c$. A massive object can never reach the limit, but the limit is still $c$.